# Cast value to Generic Protocol

Tags: swift, generics, protocols, swift-protocols

I have **Protocol**

```
public protocol ResponseListDto: Mappable {
    associatedtype Data: Mappable
    var data: [Data]! { get }

}
```

A once a time I need cast my value to this protocol, as default Data type `Mappable`. I try this

```
if var value = value as? Mappable {
    /// my calc code

    // let value = value as? ResponseListDto - Error
    if let value = value as? ResponseListDto, ResponseListDto.Data == Mappable { // - error
       for let item in value.data {
          item.mapping(map: map)
       }
    } else {
       value.mapping(map: map)
    }
}
```

but I have error all time.

> - Protocol 'ResponseListDto' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements
> - Associated type 'Data' can only be used with a concrete type or generic parameter base

How can I resolve it?

Comment: Try making the variable name something other then value e.g `if let val = value as?`

Comment: The problem is that `ResponseListDto` isn't really a type. It's a set of types containing one variant of `ResponseListDto` per possible type of `Mappable`. Casting to `ResponseListDto` doesn't make much sense, because it's unclear exactly what the type of `Data` should be